# Why can I install my app on iOS 14.1 but not 14.2?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios14, xcode12

Ever since installing Xcode 12.2, I can't install our app on simulators running iOS 14.2. I downloaded 14.1 and simulators running 14.1 install the app just fine. Tellingly, **my coworker does not have this problem even though he's running the same version of Xcode**, so a problem with my setup seems likely.

I've tried uninstalling Xcode and reinstalling. I've deleted the derivedData folder. Nothing seems to help.

The app builds just fine, but when it goes to install on a simulator running iOS 14.2, I get this popup:

[image: Cozi Needs To Be Updated]

When I click the "Details" button, I get the following:

> Details
>
> “Cozi” Needs To Be Updated Domain: IXUserPresentableErrorDomain Code:
> 4 Failure Reason: This app needs to be updated by the developer to
> work on this version of iOS. Recovery Suggestion: Failed to find
> matching arch for input file:
> /Users/j.r.willett/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/662A1CB0-4E54-4DEC-8F4B-E2CA5FCB0DE8/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.o8dPqi/extracted/iCozi-Free.app/PlugIns/NotificationService.appex/NotificationService
> -- Failed to find matching arch for input file: /Users/j.r.willett/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/662A1CB0-4E54-4DEC-8F4B-E2CA5FCB0DE8/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.o8dPqi/extracted/iCozi-Free.app/PlugIns/NotificationService.appex/NotificationService
> Domain: MIInstallerErrorDomain Code: 15 User Info: {
> FunctionName = MIMachOFileMatchesMyArchitecture;
> LegacyErrorString = IncorrectArchitecture;
> SourceFileLine = 51; }
> --
>
> System Information
>
> macOS Version 10.15.7 (Build 19H15) Xcode 12.2 (17535) (Build 12B45b)
> Timestamp: 2020-11-20T13:33:05-08:00

I don't see other people on StackOverflow reporting this error, so I seem to have stumbled into something a bit unique. I'd really appreciate any pointers!!

Edit 11/30/2020: Despite creating a bounty, I still haven't found any solution to this problem. My current plan is to wait or iOS 14.3 and hope that fixes the problem somehow.

Edit 12/16/2020: iOS 14.3 didn't help, but some more answers came in which led me to the solution, which you can see below. Thank you!!

Comment: Have you done a clean and full rebuild of your project?  The problem seems to be with the notification extension. Maybe this target hasn't been rebuilt.

Comment: Thanks @Paulw11; that was the first thing I tried :)

Comment: I've bumped into the same problem while trying to build Messages Extension on Xcode 12.2 for iOS 14.2. You're not alone. Doesn't work on my customer's machine also :/

Comment: Looks like the same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65068111/cant-build-watch-app-to-simulator-due-to-app-needs-to-be-updated

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This might help someone if still not too late. The issue in my case was caused after I added NotificationService
The steps:
Select your project -> Targets -> NotificationService (or any name you chose).
Select Build Settings -> search for VALID_ARCHS and add the value $(ARCHS_STANDARD)

Hope this helps someone struggling with the same.

Comment: This did the trick! I posted my own answer below with details, but I marked yours as the solution so hopefully you get some rep or something. Thank you!!

Comment: that did it for me, i had a stray setting in VALID_ARCHS that worked in Xcode 11 but not Xcode 12

Answer (score 2):

I've bumped into the same problem while trying to build Messages Extension on Xcode 12.2 for iOS 14.2.

This is how I've solved this problem:

1. Try to set Legacy build system (File -> Workspace Settings... -> Build System -> Legacy Build System). It shows errors in better way.
2. I've got smth like this:
   [image]

3. Removed VALID_ARCHS settings from my extension target

Comment: Your suggestions led me to the solution (which I will post as a separate answer)! Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 2):

@Nadzeya and @Sawib's suggestion led me to discover the fix for my situation!!

In my case, I needed to edit my project file and ADD some VALID_ARCHS parameters for my new extension, which were for some reason missing. Here's what my github desktop diff looked like:

[image: Diff from Github Desktop]

I can finally compile again for iOS 14.2 and 14.3. Thank you @Nadzeya and @Saqib!!

I think @Saqib's answer was the closest to what I did so I marked theirs as the correct answer.

Comment: VALID_ARCHS is deprecated in Xcode 14.3, what to do now?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the error a little closer you will see where it is complaining about the architecture being incorrect:

[image: Incorrect arch]

Review your project architecture settings, and try changing '*Build Active Architecture Only*' to **Yes** on your target like so:

[image: Active Build Arch]

This is a notable bug I have encountered since updating to Xcode 12.x. If the problem persists you can begin narrowing down the specific dependency that is causing the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @ninehundreds! I verified that all targets have "Build Active Architecture Only" set to Yes. If you have any other ideas, please share. Thanks!

Comment: @dacoinminster Can you check whether your coworker is running Xcode in legacy build mode?

Comment: He is not, nor am I. I tried building in legacy build mode and got the same results.

Comment: Have you tried downloading an earlier simulator runtime to see if you get the same error?

Comment: Yup; as noted in the original question, 14.1 works fine, but I can't install the app on 14.2

Comment: Strange that it's giving an architecture error, when there is little to no difference in 14.1 and 14.2. Have you tried manually removing the 14.2 simulator from /Library/Developer/Xcode/CoreSimulator, and then re-adding it through Xcode?

Comment: Only older versions of xcode are in that directory. 14.2 can't be removed there

Comment: @dacoinminster That might be your problem. At least on my machine I have 14.2 sims living in that folder, along with older ones. You should see a device_set.plist file which lists the sims. Not sure at this point if it would help, but maybe dump the entire folder and any caches prior to doing a reinstall.

Comment: /Users/j.r.willett/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices has the device_set.plist and describes a number of devices, whereas /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes has the downloaded older versions of iOS. I tried deleting all the devices in the first directory, restarted xcode, created a new device running 14.2; same problem.

Comment: I don't have a /Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles directory. I am not sure whether that is required. I am out of ideas. Sorry I could not be of better help.

Comment: I appreciate you trying @ninehundreds! I added a bounty so hopefully somebody else will jump in soon.