# Can't build Watch App to simulator due to App needs to be updated

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit

I've been stuck on this for a few days. Really appreciate it if anyone can point me the directions.

All of a sudden I can't build the Watch App onto the simulator - I can still build to the device tho. It shows an error as below. It looks like target architecture issue but the build settings Architectures is set to $(ARCHS_STANDARD).

After the error message was shown, the simulator had the App with unfinished install. Tapping on it triggers another dialog: This app needs to be updated by the developer to work on this version of watchOS.

```
Details

“xxx” Needs To Be Updated
Domain: IXUserPresentableErrorDomain
Code: 4
Failure Reason: This app needs to be updated by the developer to work on this version of watchOS.
Recovery Suggestion: Failed to find matching arch for input file: /Users/xxx/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/D5BAD233-3780-483A-BD6C-880255002917/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.V1pK3n/extracted/Watch.app/PlugIns/Watch Extension.appex/Watch Extension
--
Failed to find matching arch for input file: /Users/xxx/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/D5BAD233-3780-483A-BD6C-880255002917/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.V1pK3n/extracted/Watch.app/PlugIns/Watch Extension.appex/Watch Extension
Domain: MIInstallerErrorDomain
Code: 15
User Info: {
    FunctionName = MIMachOFileMatchesMyArchitecture;
    LegacyErrorString = IncorrectArchitecture;
    SourceFileLine = 51;
}

System Information

macOS Version 11.0.1 (Build 20B29)
Xcode 12.2 (17535) (Build 12B45b)
Timestamp: 2020-11-30T15:27:57+11:00
```

Comment: Maybe my solution can help you too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64937288/why-can-i-install-my-app-on-ios-14-1-but-not-14-2/65259766#65259766

Comment: @Nadzeya Thanks! Your solution did point to the right direction. All I needed was to add X86_64 to VALID_ARCH. Not sure why only the Watch Extension needs it tho...

Comment: I follow the link (which is the same direction as above, but more detailed) https://stackoverflow.com/a/65260671 and solve my problem.